# Fill dropdownmenu at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 dropdownmenu's, 1 called Sport and 1 called discipline.

In sport are 2 attributes: athletics and swimming.

Now I want to make discipline dependent upon sport.
Example: When swimming is selected in sport, discipline shows only the swimming disciplines.

What is the best method to do this?

Comment: These are known as Cascading Dropdowns - there are many samples out there (and questions here on SO on the topic).

Comment: ok, I was looking for the name. Thanks!